# HTML Form In Outlook With Post Function

Tags: html, forms, email, outlook

I would like to have an HTML email with two buttons, Approve and Reject for example.

I able to to generate the HTML email and send to outlook.

Screenshot:

[image]

The HTML code in the email:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="https://samplewebservicehere.com/wwebservice" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="P1_APPROVAL_TOKEN" value="<<APPROVAL_TOKEN>>">
        <input type="hidden" name="P1_APPROVAL_REQUEST_ID" value="<<REQUEST_ID>>">
        <hr style="width:98%" />
        <br />Hi,
        <br />
        <br />You have a request. Please kindly approve or reject by click on the buttons below
        <br />Thank You.
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="P1_ACTION" value="APPROVE" style="border-radius: 2px; background-color: #5794ff; color: #ffffff; padding: 0px 19px; height: 32px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 12px;">
        <input type="submit" name="P1_ACTION" value="REJECT" style="border-radius: 2px; background-color: #5794ff; color: #ffffff; padding: 0px 19px; height: 32px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 12px;">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on either the Approve/Reject links, it able to call the web service but without the values of P1_APPROVAL_TOKEN, P1_APPROVAL_REQUEST_ID and P1_ACTION. It works fine in web browser but not in outlook.

Comment: remove your form and change you buttons to `a` tag and your url to something like `href="https://samplewebservicehere.com/wwebservice?userinput=P1_ACTION&id=P1_APPROVAL_TOKEN&reqid=P1_APPROVAL_REQUEST_ID"` it's your job to make sure those tokens are 1 use only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use get method rather than post so you can find the data sent in the URL

Comment: I have removed the tag `form` and make it to post function, it works.